# Does it cost to use "Expose an API" in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have set up Azure AD with my Vue JS project. Now I am considering using the "expose an api" (under application) in Azure AD. But cant figure out if it costs anything.
I see that the API Managment has a price calucalted by the use (number of calls) but can not find same information on the Expose Api under Application.

Does anybody know if it cost anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Expose an API" panel is used to create scopes for restricting access for an API you have created yourself. There is no cost associated with this.